# How to display active top menu sub-items on bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I have a top menu with some items that have sub-items. If the user clicks on an item that has sub items, I want these sub-items to be displayed in the bottom menu, so that when one reaches the bottom of the page it is easy to continue to a another sub-item.

Example: If the user clicks on "First" it should look like below.

```html
<nav id='top-menu'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>First</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>Sub-first</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>Sub-second</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>Second</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<article>
  Article text
</article>

<nav id='bottom-menu'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>Sub-first</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>Sub-second</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<details>
  <summary>Heading #1</summary>
   <nav>
      <a href="#">Link A</a> 
   </nav>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Heading #1</summary>
     <nav>
       <a href="#">Link B</a> 
     </nav>
  </details>
```

with out jquery by using html5 we can do it,if you dont like comment i will update with jquery [more..in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/mtsqn5u1/)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery you can try something like this:

```
var $bottomContainer = $('#bottom-menu');
$('#top-menu a').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var $submenu = $(e.target).siblings('ul');
   if (!$submenu.length) return;

   $bottomContainer.empty().append($submenu.clone());
});
```